# Hiera variables inside a puppet manifest script

Tags: vagrant, puppet, provisioning, hiera

I have Hiera running in combination with puppet/vagrant .

Say I have a puppet exec doing following

```
      exec { create-project-database:
    command => 'mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE project_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = \'utf8\';"',
    unless  => 'mysql -u root information_schema -e "select * from information_schema.schemata;" | grep "project_db"',
    require => Package[mysql-server],
  }
```

I want to replace the string `"project_db"` with a variable I have inside my `common.yaml` of hiera

```
---
machine_message: 'This is the dev machine!'
codes_path: '/vagrant/code/laravel/'
project_db: 'project_db'
```

How I go about this? The syntax is not clear for me, and something like this brings errors:

```
    command => 'mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE 'hiera('project_db)' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = \'utf8\';"',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with your quotes in `'hiera('project_db)'` (i.e. you're not closing before the parentheses so `hiera('project_db')` should be correct)

usually I do declare variables from hiera before so something like this

```
$DB_NAME = hiera('project_db')
exec { create-project-database:
  command => "mysql -u root -e \"CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8';\"",
  unless  => 'mysql -u root information_schema -e "select * from information_schema.schemata;" | grep "project_db"',
  require => Package[mysql-server],
}
```

Comment: `command => 'mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE  $DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = \'utf8\';"',` this brings an error doing `vagrant provision`...I think the `$DB_NAME` still needs some kind of quotes or something different.

Comment: I use practically the same in exec and it runs fine. can you run puppet provisioning in debug mode and add debug(""CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME") in the exec block to see what it prints

Comment: `==> default: Error: mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE $dbName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8';" returned 1 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Initenv/Exec[create-project-database]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE $dbName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8';" returned 1 instead of one of [0]`

Comment: the variable is `$dbName = hiera('project_db')`

Comment: argh ! my bad, string interpolation works only with double quote (") so editing the command to run `command => "mysql -u root -e \"CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8';\""` should be okay now